# Store dynamic Global properties in OSGI

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have a use case in which an OSGI bundle needs to generate and store some custom property value which should be visible to all other OSGI bundles that will be deployed in OSGI container.
e.g.
1.) OSGI container (Apache Felix) starts
2.) Bundle A gets deployed
3.) Bundle A computes and stores a property (propName:propValue) somewhere in OSGI framework
4.) Bundle B/C/D gets deployed and it can access the property set in step 3.
Is there any way I can store the property as mentioned in step 3 somewhere in OSGI framework rather than using some external database ?

Comment: Is this persistence or during the life time of a framework?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Config Admin specification?